# How can migrate ESXi to the paid version

Tags: vmware-esxi, migration, vmware-vsphere, live-migration

I'm new to ESXi/vSphere and hope someone can help me.

We bought vSphere and need migrate from our free ESXi installation. I have searched a lot about process but cant find about.

We are still thinking about if we will keep the host profiler or just VM's disks.

I have two scenarios: One scenario needs move machines from one server with ESXi to another server where I will install vSphere. In the other scenario we have just one server an need make backup of VMs before clearing the disk and installing vSphere.

For the second scenario I just found [moving from ESXi to ESXi](https://serverfault.com/questions/269108/how-do-you-migrate-vmware-esxi-free-installation-and-datastore-to-a-new-drive) that doesn't solve my problem, from the first scenario I just found someone telling the both are [almost the same](https://serverfault.com/questions/630329/what-is-the-benefit-of-vsphere-standard-from-free-esxi-if-vcenter-center-is-stil).
How can i migrate from esxi to vsphere ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It might be worth you getting some training, even the most basic will get you further than you are now

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are confused about what components are involved and what you have paid for.

`ESXi` is the hypervisor that runs on the hardware.

`vSphere` is the software used to manage ESXi hosts.

When you use the free version, you get a single ESXi license that you can manage with vSphere. When you purchase the software you are able to run more that one instance of ESXi and you also get access to `vCenter`, a management server that handles all of your ESXi hosts in a single place. If you are going to run several ESXi hosts you will want to set up your vCenter server first.

As far as the upgrade / migration process goes, it is simply a matter of going into the vSphere software and updating your license keys from your free ones to the new ones that you purchased. If you have vCenter set up you can manage the licenses for all of your ESXi hosts in one place.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I just need install vSphere above current environment by installing licences.